# Let $S=\{ \mathcal{X_s} \;\;|\;\;\ s\in\mathbb{R} \}$. It is possible that $ Span(S) = \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $S=\{ \mathcal{X_s} \;\;|\;\;\ s\in\mathbb{R} \}$. 
It is possible that $ Span(S)=\langle S\rangle = \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}=\{f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \; |\;\; f\;\;\ fuction  \}$? 
I do not think this is possible, but I can not prove it. Can anyone give me a hint on how to prove this or a counter example. I also wanted a hint on how to describe the subspace generated $Span(S)=\langle S\rangle.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $\chi_s(x)$ is $0$, unless $x=s$, in which case it is equal to $1$. If that's so, you are right, since every element of $\operatorname{span}(S)$ is $0$ outside a finite set.

Comment: Can you explain to me why outside a finite set $span (S) = \{ 0 \}$?

Comment: I did not write that. Fortunately, since it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused, I wanted to know if you have a way of describing the generated subspace $span(S)$

Comment: Sure: it's the space of those functions $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,|\,f(x)\neq0\}$ is finite.